# Issue with imports/exports in library since migrating to angular 9 and Ivy

Tags: angular, angular9, angular-ivy, inline-svg

I am using **ng-inline-svg** (latest version i.e. 10.0.0) and I am trying to migrate a library to **angular 9 with Ivy**. Since updating the angular version, I get the following error:

```
ERROR in Symbol InlineSVGModule declared in C:/git/XXX/node_modules/ng-inline-svg/lib_commonjs/inline-svg.module.d.ts is not exported from ng-inline-svg (import into C:/git/XXX/src/app/app.module.ts)
```

I have imported the inline svg module as follows in `app.module.ts`:

```
InlineSVGModule.forRoot(),
```

Can someone please help?

**edit**: Please note that this happens when building in **aot**

Comment: i am getting same error , have you found any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

as temporary solution you can try disable ivy in your tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false,
    "allowEmptyCodegenFiles": true
  }
}
```